# “stdin is not a terminal” quando eu executo o Envoy - Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, osx

Um mês atrás tudo está funcionando bem, até que fui fazer o deploy de um projeto e...

Quando execute o comando `envoy run deploy`, utilizando as configurações abaixo...

```
@servers([
    'mt' => 'user@xxxx.xxxx.xxxx'
])

@task('deploy', ['on' => 'mt'])
    cd /var/www/html/xxx.xxxxxx.xxxx
    git pull origin dev
    composer dump-autoload -o
    php artisan cache:clear
@endtask
```

Eu obtive o seguinte erro:

```
git:(dev) ✗ envoy run deploy
[]: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
[]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname bash -s: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Coloquei o conteúdo do arquivo `id_rsa.pub` do meu mac no servidor, dentro do arquivo `authorized_keys`, e consigo fazer o login normalmente da maneira tradicional: `ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx` - (sem a senha).

Então... o que estou fazendo errado? O que mudou no Envoy?

Se precisarem de mais informações, me avisem antes de negativarem a questão.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você precisa de algum arquivo PEM para conectar no host? Já tentou reverter a versão do `laravel/envoy` para a versão de um mês atrás para ver se resolve?

Comment: Não tentei reverter Rodrigo. E não, eu só peguei o arquivo `id_rsa.pub`, coloquei no `authorized_keys` na VPS e pronto.

Comment: Tente reverter a versão antes de tudo para ver se resolve, já que é fácil de fazê-lo (só mudar a versão no `composer.json` e atualizar as dependências).

Comment: Vou ter que ir voltando uma por uma pois não lembro a última vez que atualizei o projeto. Mas enfim, vou tentar hoje à noite e aviso aqui assim que possível.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei a solução, mas até agora não estou acreditando que seja isso.

Esse é o meu código.

```
@servers([
    'mt' => 'user@xxxx.xxxx.xxxx'
])
```

Essa é a solução:

```
@servers(['mt' => 'user@xxxx.xxxx.xxxx'])
```

A função `@servers` aceita apenas instruções **inline**.

Obrigado pelo tempo de vocês galera!.
Abs.

Comment: A sério que era isso?

Comment: Sério, nem acreditei. Estou travado nisso a 1 semana e meia e era só isso. Inacreditável.